# Put more than one clause into my sqlite query with ormlite

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, where-clause, ormlite

How can I put more than one clause into my sqlite query?

I've tried something like

```
where().in("idCampo", alternativas);
```

but it does not work.

**alternativas** is an array of longs, I want something that gives me

```
"idCampo" = alternativas.get(0) and "idCampo" = alternativas.get(1)....
```

Comment: You have to compare some value with your in clause.

Comment: Now it works! Thanks Marc

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  In the future, please make sure that you provide the exact details around "it does not work".  What error did you get?  What exception including the caused-by.  Also, I think you mean that you want something that is `get(0)` _or_ `get(1)`, right?  Lastly if you have solved your problem you should either delete this question or post an answer with the details.

Comment: If you have solved your problem you should either delete this question or post an answer with the details.